# Differential Equation : $\frac{dy}{dx} -2xy = e^{x^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My study buddy and I are getting different answers for this one.

Here is the equation:
$\frac{dy}{dx} -2xy = e^{x^2}$

And my solution

$P(x) = -2x  
\implies   I(x)= e^{-x^2}$

$I(x)*\frac{dy}{dx} - 2xyI(x) = e^{x^2}  I(x)$

$e^{-x^2}\frac{dy}{dx} - 2xye^{-x^2}$ = $e^{x^2}e^{-x^2}$

$\frac {d(-2yx)}{dx}=e^{x^2}e^{-x^2}$

Since $e^{x^2} * e^{-x^2} = e^{0} = 1$

Therefore, $-2yx = 1 + c$

If I'm doing something wrong, please show me! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with your original equation
$$\frac{dy}{dx}-2xy=e^{x^2}$$
Finding the integrating factor
$$\mu(x) =e^{\int{-2xdx}} = e^{-x^2}$$
Multiplying our integrating factor to both sides of the equation
$$\mu(x)\frac{dy}{dx}-2x\mu(x)y=e^{x^2}\mu(x)=e^{x^2}e^{-x^2}=1$$
The left hand side of our equation is just the expanded product rule derivative, hence:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left[\mu(x)y\right]=1$$
Integrating both sides with respect to $x$:
$$\mu(x)y=x+C$$
Finally we just do some algebra to isolate $y$ and then simplify:$$y=\frac{1}{\mu(x)}(x+c)=e^{x^2}(x+C)=Ce^{x^2}+xe^{x^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

You did something wonky with your integration factor. After multiplying the equation through with the integration factor your equation should have been
$$\left(I(x)y\right)'=e^{x^2}I(x)$$
since $I(x)\frac{dy}{dx}-2xyI(x)=(I(x)y)'$.
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

In your displayed line above the word "Since", you've dropped the integrating factor on the left side.  Inside the derivative should be an $e^{-x^2}.$